# Обновление ListView в Fragment setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)

Tags: java, android

Как обновить `ListView` в методе `setUserVisibleHint`, если

```
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

только в `onCreateView`. А при вызове в `setUserVisibleHint` возникает `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так получилось.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // сейчас фрагмент виден юзеру
    }else{
       // Обновляйте тут, фрагмент не видим юзеру
       if(getView()!=null) { /* тут ListView не будет null */ }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

я так понимаю у вас есть метод `setUserVisibleHint`, в таком случае обьявите в начале класса - `private ListView mListView`, а метод `setUserVisibleHint` вызывайте после того как вызовите `findViewById`, ну или код в студию.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView mListView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        setUserVisibleHint();
        return view;
    }
```

}

Comment: Да, но этот метод вызывается только при скрытии фрагмента, а 'findViewById' вызывается в видимом фрагменте в методе 'onCreateView'.

Comment: Вы вызываете setUserVisibleHint в onPause?, лучше скиньте код класса и кейс возникновения. Так быстрее дадут правильный ответ

Answer (score 2):

Насколько мне известно, сей метод может вызываться в т.ч до создания разметки фрагмента. Но, если вы данные для списка формируете и храните в классе фрагмента и лишь отображаете их в `ListView`, то просто обновляйте эти данные в вашем методе, а назначайте их лишь после проверки того, что `listView!=null`

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте `listView` полем класса.

Comment: Можно подробнее, на примере?