# Как сделать, чтоб метод выполнялся только когда открыт нужный фрагмент?

Tags: java, android

У меня реализован `TabLayout` с 2-мя табами и в них фрагменты...

В первом табе у меня показывается список друзей, а во втором список входящих сообщений...

Когда юзер переходит из `MainActivity` к таб `friends` то открывается `progress dialog` и в `AssynTask` начинается загрузка друзей и по окончанию показывается `RecyclerView` с полным списком друзей.

Так вот вопрос в том, что когда юзер из `MainActivity` открывает таб `inbox` то у меня все равно то открывается `progress dialog` и в `AssynTask` начинается загрузка друзей из таба `friends`.

Я рассчитываю что `AssynTask` должен срабатывать только в случае когда юзер открывает таб `friends`...

Что делаю не так?

Вот код :

```
public final class FriendsInboxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

private TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_left_padding);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    setUI();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra(States.INDEX_OF_TAB)) {
        int index = intent.getIntExtra(States.INDEX_OF_TAB, 0);
        switchTab(index);
    }        
}

private void switchTab(int index) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(index);
    if (tab != null) {
        tab.select();
    }
}



private void setUI() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.friends));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.inbox));

    final int NUMBER_OF_TABS = 2;
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    TabFriendsAdapter tabFriendsAdapter = new TabFriendsAdapter(fragmentManager, NUMBER_OF_TABS);

    viewPager.setAdapter(tabFriendsAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}    
}
```

Вот таб `friends`

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

private View rootView;

public FriendsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
    fetchContacts();
    return rootView;
}

private void fetchContacts(){
    int size = SingletonForCardFriend.getInstance().getSize();
    if (size > 0) {
        setUI();
    } else {
        new ContactsReader().execute();
    }
}

private void setUI() {
    RecyclerView rvFriends = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvFriends);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvFriends.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    List<CardFriend> friends = SingletonForCardFriend.getInstance().getListOfFriends();
    FriendsAdapter friendsAdapter = new FriendsAdapter(friends);
    rvFriends.setAdapter(friendsAdapter);
}

private class ContactsReader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Dialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = UtilClass.getDialog(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
        progressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        readContacts();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        setUI();
    }
```

и вот `inbox`

```
public class InboxFragment extends Fragment {

public InboxFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);
    RecyclerView rvInbox = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvInbox);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvInbox.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

Адаптер

```
public class FriendsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendsAdapter.FriendViewHolder> {

List<CardFriend> friends;

public FriendsAdapter(List<CardFriend> friends) {
    this.friends = friends;
}

public static class FriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView friendName;
    TextView friendNumber;
    ImageView friendPhoto;
    TextView friendEmail;

    FriendViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        friendName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonName);
        friendNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonNumber);
        friendPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPersonPhoto);
        friendEmail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonEmail);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return friends.size();
}

@Override
public FriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_friend, viewGroup, false);
    return new FriendViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FriendViewHolder friendViewHolder, int i) {
    friendViewHolder.friendName.setText(friends.get(i).getFriendName());
    friendViewHolder.friendNumber.setText(friends.get(i).getFriendNumber());
    friendViewHolder.friendPhoto.setImageResource(friends.get(i).getPhotoId());
    friendViewHolder.friendEmail.setText(friends.get(i).getFriendEmail());
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
}
```

Как сделать, чтоб код работал предсказуемо?)

Comment: Почитайте, как работают адаптеры. Кроме текущего фрагмента, наперед загружаются еще левый и правый. То же самое с ListView.

Comment: @metalurgus так идея получается такая, что нужно как то сделать так, чтоб адаптер загружал фрагмент, только тогда когда юзер переключается на него? Я думал как то в методе `onAtached()` сделать... Но у меня не получилось...

Comment: вы можете установить лисенер на изменение вкладки, и в этом лисенере сообщать фрагменту, что надо загрузить данные, как только переключились на него

Comment: Аналоги дубля: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498476/ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498841

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Все работает, спасибо!